# ColorFunction for StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, color, streams

I would like to color all lines witch have a positive vertical component in red and the other in blue. How can I do that?

```
μ0 = 4 Pi 10^-7;
(*1 magnet*)
r1[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};
m1[θ1_, ϕ_, p_ ] := p {Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ1], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ1], Cos[ϕ]};
(*2 magnet*)
r2[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};
m2[θ1_, ϕ_, p_ ] := p {Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ1], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ1], Cos[ϕ]};
M = 16.7 10^-3;
g = 9.81;

Field[x_, y_, z_, θ1_, ϕ1_, p1_] := μ0/(4 π ) ((3 m1[θ1, ϕ1, p1] . r2[x, y, z])/Norm[r2[x, y, z]]^5 r2[x, y, z] - m1[θ1, ϕ1, p1]/Norm[r2[x, y, z]]^3)

Manipulate[
 Show[
  StreamPlot[
   Field[x, 0, z, ϕ, Pi/2,  2.07][[1 ;; 3 ;; 2]],
   {x, -0.05, 0.05},  {z, -0.05, 0.05},
    ImageSize -> Medium, FrameLabel -> {"x", "z"}, 
   StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
  ], {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all other code the same as in the question, use the option [`StreamColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamColorFunction.html)

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[
  Field[x, 0, z, ϕ, Pi/2, 2.07][[1 ;; 3 ;; 2]],
  {x, -0.05, 0.05}, {z, -0.05, 0.05},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "z"},
  StreamColorFunction ->
   Function[{x, z, vx, vz, n}, If[vz > 0, Red, Blue]],
  StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 {{ϕ, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {ϕ}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit of a kluge, because in `StreamPlot`, the arrows are curved, so I had to make a choice as to what constituted "up" and what constituted "down.  Here's how I made the choice. The arrows in the plot are stored internally in the form of

```
Arrow[listOfPoints]
```

where `listOfPoints` is the list of points that define the curve of the arrow.  I took the *last* two points in the list, and if the y-value of the last element was less than or equal to the y-value of the second-to-last element, I made the arrow blue by making the replacement

```
Arrow[lst_] :> {Blue, Arrow[lst]}
```

Then, I set all of the rest of the arrows red in the same way. One could make a different choice.  For instance, we could replace the condition I chose with one that *averages* over the length of the curve, and if it is "mostly" pointing down, then make it blue.

Code follows:

```
μ0 = 4 Pi 10^-7;
(*1 magnet*)
r1[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};
m1[θ1_, ϕ_, p_ ] := p {Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ1], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ1], Cos[ϕ]};
(*2 magnet*)
r2[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};
m2[θ1_, ϕ_, p_ ] := p {Sin[ϕ] Cos[θ1], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ1], Cos[ϕ]};
M = 16.7 10^-3;
g = 9.81;

Field[x_, y_, z_, θ1_, ϕ1_, p1_] := μ0/(4 π ) ((3 m1[θ1, ϕ1, p1] . r2[x, y, z])/Norm[r2[x, y, z]]^5 r2[x, y, z] - m1[θ1, ϕ1, p1]/Norm[r2[x, y, z]]^3)

Manipulate[
 Show[
  StreamPlot[
   Field[x, 0, z, ϕ, Pi/2,  2.07][[1 ;; 3 ;; 2]],
   {x, -0.05, 0.05},  {z, -0.05, 0.05},
    ImageSize -> Medium, FrameLabel -> {"x", "z"}, 
   StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
  ], {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]

Normal@p1 /. {Arrow[lst_] /; lst[[-1, 2]] - lst[[-2, 2]] >= 0 :> {Blue, Arrow[lst]}, x_Arrow :> {Red, x}}
```

[image]

TO make this work in `Manipulate`, do

```
Manipulate[
 p1 = Show[
   StreamPlot[Field[x, 0, z, ϕ, Pi/2, 2.07][[1 ;; 3 ;; 2]],
   {x, -0.05, 0.05}, {z, -0.05, 0.05},
   ImageSize -> Medium, FrameLabel -> {"x", "z"}, StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
   ];
 Normal@p1 /. {Arrow[lst_] /; lst[[-1, 2]] - lst[[-2, 2]] >= 0 :> {Blue, Arrow[lst]} , x_Arrow :> {Red, x}},
 {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```